# How to move through words and break on punctuation on terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut

I changed laptop and I cannot configure my Terminal the way it was.

I had this shortcut to delete words, and when deleting ab-cd.ef_gh, it would go ab-cd.ef_ then ab-cd. then ab- then nothing. So it would break on hyphens and on other such characters. But the behaviour now is to delete the full sequence ab-cd.ef_gh instead of doing it "one by one". How can I do that?

Comment: Just for clarity - deletion used to delete “-gh” and not “gh”? In another words break was after “-“.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I don't remember well but I think you are right, let me edit. Also it was any punctuation

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on [Super user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258661/46465)

The issue was that Mac went from bash to zsh. There is nothing about a shortcut to "delete part of a word". The solution is to use the common "delete word" shortcut and **define what a word is**: bash defines a word to be a-zA-Z0-9 but not zsh which defines words as anything in between spaces (so ab.cd or /ef/gh/ij).

for the sake of completeness, add to your .zshrc:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```